# Java.-Llenar dos arreglos desde teclado y compararlos

Tags: java, array

Me piden llenar 2 arreglos desde teclado y finalmente compararlos, si son iguales imprimir 1 y si son diferentes imprimir 0, podrian ayudarme a realizarlo de la forma correcta?

Entrada:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Salida:

```
1
```

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int N= sc.nextInt();
    int N1 = sc.nextInt();
    int [] Sec1=new int[N1];
    int N2 = sc.nextInt();
    int [] Sec2=new int[N2];

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<N; i++){
        Sec1[i]=i;
        Sec2[j]=j;
        if(Sec1[i]==Sec2[j]){
      System.out.println("1");
      break;
    }else{
      System.out.println("0");
      break;
    }
      }
    }
     }
}
```

Claramente mi codigo esta mal pero es lo mejor que pude hacer ya que soy nuevo con este lenguaje y quiero aprenderlo pero no se realizar un ejercicio que parece ser facil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para comparar Array's puedes usar [**Arrays.equals**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D)).

> Devuelve verdadero si las dos matrices de ints especificadas son iguales entre sí. Dos matrices se consideran iguales si ambas contienen el mismo número de elementos y todos los pares de elementos correspondientes en las dos matrices son iguales. En otras palabras, dos matrices son iguales si contienen los mismos elementos en el mismo orden. Además, dos referencias de matriz se consideran iguales si ambas son nulas.
>
> **Parámetros:**
>
> - a - una matriz para probar la igualdad
> - a2 - la otra matriz que se probará para determinar la igualdad
>
> **Devoluciones:**
> verdadero si las dos matrices son iguales

Te dejo un ejemplo con tu código modificado:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del array1");
        int N1 = sc.nextInt();
        int []Sec1=new int[N1];
        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del array2");
        int N2 = sc.nextInt();
        int []Sec2=new int[N2];
        
        // Llenamos de datos los array's
        System.out.println("Ingrese los datos del primer array");
        for (int i = 0; i < N1; i++) {
            Sec1[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Ingrese los datos del segundo array");
        for (int i = 0; i < N2; i++) {
            Sec2[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        
        // Comparamos los arrays
        if (Arrays.equals(Sec1, Sec2))
            System.out.println("Salida: " + 1);
        else
            System.out.println("Salida: " + 0);
    }
}
```

Si necesitas hacerlo sin usar `Arrays.equals` puedes hacer lo siguiente (Te dejo el código comentado):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del array1");
        int N1 = sc.nextInt();
        int []Sec1=new int[N1];
        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del array2");
        int N2 = sc.nextInt();
        int []Sec2=new int[N2];
        
        // Llenamos de datos los array's
        System.out.println("Ingrese el primer array");
        for (int i = 0; i < N1; i++) {
            Sec1[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Ingrese el segundo array");
        for (int i = 0; i < N2; i++) {
            Sec2[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        if (Sec1.length == Sec2.length) { // Comparamos si el tamaño de los arrays son iguales (Si no imprime 0 directamente)
            boolean diferente = false; // Si alguno es diferente cambia a true
            for (int i = 0; i < Sec1.length; i++) {
                if (Sec1[i] != Sec2[i]) { // Si encuentra algún dato diferente entra aquí
                    diferente = true;
                    break; // Detiene el for para que ya no busque con los siguientes
                }
            }
            if (diferente) // Si diferente es verdadero imprime 0
                System.out.println("Salida: 0");
            else
                System.out.println("Salida: 1");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Salida: 0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya vi en que partes de equivoque, te lo agradezco